# Playing wav sound file with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, wav

I am using AVFoundation to play wav files. But i could not make it play. Also no errors or warnings showed up.

XCode is 4.2 and device is iOS 5.

```
- (IBAction) playSelectedAlarm:(id)sender {

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

int bTag = button.tag;

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d23333", bTag];

NSLog(@"%@", fileName);

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"wav"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];

AVAudioPlayer *theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:NULL];

theAudio.volume = 1.0;

theAudio.delegate = self;

[theAudio prepareToPlay];

[theAudio play];

}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not ignoring any possible errors (as you are within the initWithContentsOfUrl call). Use proper NSError-objects and print their results to the console.

Comment: also check whether you forgot to add Audio Foundation framework.

Comment: @SumitLonkar: Double checked :)

Comment: @Till 

Still got no error.

`NSError *audioError = nil;
    
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&audioError];
       
    if(audioError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"An audio error occurred: \"%@\"", audioError);
    }
    else {
        [theAudio prepareToPlay];
        [theAudio play];
    }`

Comment: WAV is a format I would actually not use - try converting that file to AIFF or CAF and use the result. The WAV-Container format has gone through some slight irregularities sometimes introducing playback failures.

Comment: Converted them to CAF but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution;

I set AVAudioPlayer in header file..

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;

i guess 'retain' is solved my problem. Because after i sending "play", it sends "release" to balance the alloc. When AVAudioPlayer is deallocated it stops playing audio.

Comment: if i upload audio  file by select the MPMediaPickerController then play in background .Music thumbnail not show at home screen.how can solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same issue with Xcode 4.5. Making the AVAudioPlayer into a strongly typed property made it play.

So the following code needs added to the @interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
```

The @implementation would then become:

```
- (IBAction) playSelectedAlarm:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    int bTag = button.tag;

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d23333", bTag];

    NSLog(@"%@", fileName);

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"wav"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];

    self.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:NULL];

    self.theAudio.volume = 1.0;

    self.theAudio.delegate = self;

    [self.theAudio prepareToPlay];

    [self.theAudio play];

}
```

Comment: If you use a weak property (or a local variable) and you're using ARC, iOS will detect that there are no strong pointers to the AVAudioPlayer object and free it before you want the object removed.  The strong pointer retains the object, preventing it from being removed until you explicitly nil out the property.