# iOS 5 - play audio file in the background when the app is launched

Tags: ios5

I'm new to iOS and developing an app.
I've been searching all over to get a simple example on how to play an audio file in the background when an app is launched. Since the app that I'm developing is related to music lessons, I need this audio to be playing when the home screen is active. This is what I've done so far...

1. Created a home screen (UIViewController) with some background images and a button to navigate further into the app.
2. Set up "Required background mode" in the .plist
3. Add the audio file into the project
4. In my controller I have the following code block.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];   

       //Set some labels here
       //Set a background image

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"shrutiFsharp" ofType:@"mp3"]]; 
        AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
       [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

       [audioPlayer play];

   }
   ```

All the labels, background image, buttons show up fine.. and I'm able to navigate to another view. But when I'm on the home screen, I just cannot get the audio file to play. I'm running the iPhone 5.0 simulator.

I don't see any error messages in the console.

The code you see here is from an example that was already posted.. but I'm not quite sure why this does not work. I'm probably missing something dearly. Any help is appreciated.

-KD

Answer (score 0):

You should use the error parameters the way they were intended. It's entirely likely the audio player is trying to tell you exactly why it can't continue, but you're ignoring it!

```
NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                                    error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"audio player error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found the solution on this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323294/playing-wav-sound-file-with-avfoundation. I moved the audioPlayer declaration with (non-atomic,retain) (i need to understand what it means) to the .h and synthesized it in the .m and it works!